# Postgresql query with many phones for one people

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, one for people and another for telephone, and some people may have more than one telephone. In a query with LEFT JOIN, it is returning duplicated lines according to the number of telephones. I would like to generate a query that returns something like the table below. Is it possible?

```
id  | names | phones
-----------------------------------
id1 | Name1 | phone1,phone2,phone3
id2 | Name2 | phone1
id3 | Name3 | phone1
id4 | Name4 | phone1,phone2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select p.pid,p.name,string_agg(t.tval,',') from people p
left join telephone t
on p.tid = t.tid
group by p.pid, p.name
order by p.pid;
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/852xyoQCRpFQt3SxrPLSVF/1).